# How do you access the number of times a delegate has been called?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, events, delegates

I am currently writing a test for a piece of functionality. I need to count how many times an event handler has been called. In this example I want to ensure the delegate 'failureHandler' is never called.

I have achieved what I want from a test perspective by doing an Assert.Fail() if it is called. What I want do though is count the number of times a delegate is called for use in other parts of the test.

I believe I read somewhere you could access this information via property but I can't remember where I read it!

```
Action failureHandler = 
                completed => Assert.Fail("Not all tasks have been completed");

_testObj.TaskCompletedForItems += failureHandler;
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing it with `GetInvocationList()`? I'm not sure it is possible to count without doing it yourself ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no standard property for that... but you can easily use the fact that a lambda expression is a closure to emulate it:

```
int callCount = 0;
Action handler = () => callCount++;

_testObj.TaskCompletedForItems += handler;
// Do stuff

Assert.AreEqual(expectedCount, callCount);
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe this answer most accurately answers my question. I would refer people to dcastro's answer for a more flexible and elegant solution for unit tests using the Moq framework.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [MOQ](https://github.com/Moq/moq4), and verify how many times the action has been invoked:

```
Mock<Action> mockAction = new Mock<Action>();
Action action = mockAction.Object;

//call action
action();

//verify that it was never called
mockAction.Verify(act => act(), Times.Never());

//or verify that it has been called exactly once
mockAction.Verify(act => act(), Times.Once());
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I never considered mocking an Action - this makes for a really clean test!